# Rails group a record by only its first digit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following stuff in my DB:

```
postcode
66
2
34
25
54
98
1
14
5
39
37
```

Now what is a nice way to group this records by only the first digit (and count it)?
So the hash output is sth. like this:

```
1 => 2
5 => 2
9 => 1
3 => 3
```

etc

```
Model.group(:postcode).count
```

would be the standard query here to consider both digits. Is there any addition needed?
Or should I straight modify the DB and cut the 2nd digit (I don't want that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the postcode from db as an `Array`

```
array = Model.pluck(:postcode)
```

Group by first digit, map values array to get count

```
Hash[ array.group_by {|n| n.to_s[0] }.map {|k, v| [k.to_i, v.size]  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grouped_by = ['65', '15', '11', '29','4','56'].group_by { |n| n[0] }
# {"6"=>["65"], "1"=>["15", "11"], "2"=>["29"], "4"=>["4"], "5"=>["56"]}

grouped_by.map{ |k,v| {k => v.count} }
# [{"6"=>1}, {"1"=>2}, {"2"=>1}, {"4"=>1}, {"5"=>1}]
```

It first groups by the first digit and then maps over the resulting hash and replaces the values with the count of the values.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure SQL implementation:

```
Model.group("SUBSTR(CAST(postcode as CHAR), 1, 1)").count
```